# Bash function with flags where either is optional?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a Bash function to essentially alias deleting a local and a remote Git branch. I'd like it to be run like so:

```
$ db -r <branch_name> // deletes remote branch with name <branch_name>
$ db -l <branch_name> // deletes local branch with name <branch_name>
$ db -lr <branch_name> // deletes local and remote with <branch_name>
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
db () {
    declare opt
    declare OPTARG
    declare OPTIND

    has_l_option=false
    has_r_option=false

    while getopts :r:l: opt; do
        case $opt in
            r) has_r_option=true ;;
            l) has_l_option=true ;;
            :) echo "Missing argument for option -$OPTARG"; exit 1;;
           \?) echo "Unknown option -$OPTARG"; exit 1;;
        esac
    done

    shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

    if $has_l_option && $has_r_option; then
        git branch -d $1
        git push origin --delete $1
    elif $has_l_option; then
        git branch -d $1
    elif $has_r_option; then
        git push origin --delete $1
    else
        echo "Something went wrong"
    fi
}
```

I'd also love to abstract the `git branch -d` and `git push origin --delete` calls to other functions to avoid duplication, but I'm having a hard time doing that in Bash.

Comment: in my opinion this few duplication is hardly worth the hassle to outsource it into it its own function. what exactly is giving you problems?

Comment: The two options are independent; don't test them together. `$has_l_option && git branch -d "$1"; $has_r_option && git push origin --delete "$1"`.

Comment: The option string "`:r:l:`" implies that `-l` and `-r` each take an option argument -- that is, if you use both, you'd need to use the syntax `db -r <r_branch> -l <l_branch>` (and you'd use `$OPTARG` in the loop to access them). I'm pretty sure you want `:rl` instead.

Comment: @Sam, fair enough. I just figured I'd learn how to call helper functions in bash along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

```
# Takes -r or -l and a branch name
# and deletes the local and/or remote branch with that name
db () {
    declare opt
    declare OPTARG
    declare OPTIND

    BRANCH_NAME="$2"
    HAS_L_OPTION=false
    HAS_R_OPTION=false

    while getopts :rl opt; do
        case "$opt" in
            r) HAS_R_OPTION=true ;;
            l) HAS_L_OPTION=true ;;
            :) echo "Missing argument for option -$OPTARG"; return 1;;
           \?) echo "Unknown option -$OPTARG"; return 1;;
        esac
    done

    shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

    perform_branch_deletes_given "$BRANCH_NAME" "$HAS_L_OPTION" "$HAS_R_OPTION"

    echo "All done!"
}

# Helper
perform_branch_deletes_given () {
    BRANCH_NAME="$1"
    L="$2"
    R="$3"

    if "$L"; then
        git branch -D "$BRANCH_NAME"
    fi

    if "$R"; then
        git fetch -p origin  # prune local "cache" of remote branches
        echo "Local 'cache' of remote branches pruned"

        git push origin --delete "$BRANCH_NAME"
    fi
}
```

## Original

Alright, here's something that works:

```
db () {
    declare opt
    declare OPTARG
    declare OPTIND

    has_l_option=false
    has_r_option=false

    while getopts :rl opt; do
        case $opt in
            r) has_r_option=true ;;
            l) has_l_option=true ;;
            :) echo "Missing argument for option -$OPTARG"; exit 1;;
           \?) echo "Unknown option -$OPTARG"; exit 1;;
        esac
    done

    shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

    if $has_l_option; then
        git branch -d $1
    fi

    if $has_r_option; then
        git push origin --delete $1
    fi
}
```

Comment: The 2nd one doesn't work because you haven't shifted the options, so "$1" contains the first option to the function. I use the 1st style: use getopts to process the options *only* and do the real work after.

Comment: You should also localize the "has*option" variables.

Comment: And, depending on your preference, you can write `$has_l_option && git branch -d "$1"`

Comment: Don't forget to quote your variables: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: And add a test for $1 after you shift `if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then error and return; fi`

Comment: That second one would run those git commands in the order the flags were given (so `-rl` would be different from `-lr`). That's not what your other scripts do.

Comment: The first one is better. You should always parse and validate all flags before acting on them. I wish that was the solution everyone arrived at first

Comment: Oh, and, since it's a function, you probably want to `return 1`, instead of `exit 1` in the error cases

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner update 4 years after asking...

```
# Takes -r or -l and a branch name
# and deletes the local and/or remote branch with that name
gdb () {
    declare opt
    declare OPTARG
    declare OPTIND

    local branch_name="$2"
    local L=false
    local R=false

    while getopts :rl opt; do
        case "$opt" in
            l) L=true ;;
            r) R=true ;;
            :) echo "Missing argument for option -$OPTARG"; return 1 ;;
           \?) echo "Unknown option -$OPTARG"; return 1 ;;
        esac
    done

    shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

    if [ "$L" = false ] && [ "$R" = false ]; then   
        echo No flags passed. Use -r for remote and/or -l for local branches.
        return 1
    fi

    __delete_branches "$branch_name" "$L" "$R"

    # Show remaining local branches
    git branch -l
}

# Helpers
__delete_branches () {
    local branch_name="$1"
    local L="$2"
    local R="$3"
    local safe_branches=("master" "development" "dev" "develop")

    for safe_branch in ${safe_branches[@]}; do
        if [[ "$branch_name" == "$safe_branch" ]]; then
            echo "$branch_name" should not be deleted!
            return 1
        fi
    done

    if "$L"; then
        __delete_local_git_branch "$branch_name"
    fi

    if "$R"; then
        __delete_remote_git_branch "$branch_name"
    fi
}

__delete_local_git_branch () {
    local branch_name="$1"
    git branch -D "$branch_name"
}

__delete_remote_git_branch () {
    local branch_name="$1"
    git fetch -p origin  # prune local "cache" of remote branches
    echo Local cache of remote branches pruned

    git push origin --delete "$branch_name"
}
```